# How to Set HorizontalContentAlignment in RibbonButton

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon-control

In normal WPF **Button** control, `HorizontalContentAlignment` can set the Content of the Button the left. But in **RibbonButton** control, there is no Content, but replaced by **Label**, which cannot be aligned by `HorizontalContentAlignment`.

How to horizontal align Label of RibbonControl? Or, is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

There absolutely is a `Content` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` in RibbonButton, it inherits from Button, just check [the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonbutton.aspx).

Comment: the Content doesn't do anything to the RibbonButton. It behave different than the Content of a normal WPF button.